# Securing a Web API without user authentication

Tags: cordova, authentication, asp.net-web-api

I'm building an app that will call a Web API but logging in is optional, how do I ensure that calls to the API is being made by my app? Is it possible at all? I am using Cordova and .Net 4.6.1.

I am not a web developer by trade but have done some:)

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to take a look at jwt.io. I do not have experience with .NET, but since jwt tokens are language agnostic, you should give it a try.

Comment: You must know who the caller is if you want to restrict to certain users. I would suggest a token based approach.

Comment: Please explain why this was down voted?

Answer (score 2):

You can make your app more secure by following these steps:

1. Use ssl
2. Check the ssl certificate by using this plugin: http://plugreg.com/plugin/EddyVerbruggen/SSLCertificateChecker-PhoneGap-Plugin
3. Get the package name of your app with this plugin https://github.com/whiteoctober/cordova-plugin-app-version and send the package name along with your request.
4. If you want to have a unique ID for every device, you can generate some uuid in your app or you can use this plugin https://github.com/Paldom/UniqueDeviceID
5. I do some «Math» on the first request for checking if it is my app, which is doing the request.
6. After the first request, the app gets some token, which is also sent along with every request.
7. If you want, you can crypt your cordova app, use this plugin: https://github.com/tkyaji/cordova-plugin-crypt-file

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I will check which are practical in my scenario. Your suggestions seem to be more towards securing the app, I'm more concerned with call to the api from hackers as DOS attack for example

Answer (score 1):

Normally you should use the OAuth2 [client credentials flow](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-1.3.4) for this. But that requires your client (phone app) to be able to keep the client secret safe.

Mobile applications are considered insecure since it's hard to hide things from the owner of the device.

If you can't do client authentication, your only two options are to make user authentication a requirement, or leave your API open to any clients.

Comment: This is looking like my unfortunate future :)